# How to prove T Z = Z for binary representation of natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq

I have defined an Inductive in Coq for binary representation of natural numbers as follows:

```
Inductive bin : Type :=
  | Z : bin
  | T : bin -> bin
  | M : bin -> bin.
```

and two recursive functions to convert between nat and bin types as:

```
Fixpoint nat_to_bin (n : nat) : bin :=
  match n with
    | O => Z
    | S n' => incr (nat_to_bin n')
  end.
```

and

```
Fixpoint bin_to_nat (b : bin) : nat :=
  match b with
    | Z => O
    | M b' => S (mult 2 (bin_to_nat b'))
    | T b' => mult 2 (bin_to_nat b')
  end.
```

to show that bin_to_nat is the inverse of nat_to_bin I need to prove that `T Z = Z` by using these tactics that I know: `simpl reflexivity destruct rewrite replace induction` please recommend some clues showing how to do this. Thank you!

**Edit**

The incr implementation is

```
Fixpoint incr (b : bin) : bin :=
  match b with
    | Z => M Z
    | T b' => M b'
    | M b' => T (incr b')
  end.
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662889/how-do-we-know-all-coq-constructors-are-injective-and-disjoint/32666278

Comment: What do `T` and `M` represent? What is the implementation of `incr`? These might help us give good answers.

Comment: @cody `T` doubles its argument and returns the result, `M` doubles its argument, adds one to it and returns the result, `incr` just adds one to a binary number we have given to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> to show that `bin_to_nat` is the inverse of `nat_to_bin` I need to prove that `T Z = Z`

No, you can't prove that `T Z = Z` because it is false:

```
Lemma TZ_neq_Z : T Z <> Z.
Proof.
  discriminate.
Qed.
```

Indeed, distinct constructors of an inductive type always lead to distinct terms.

That doesn't mean you can't prove that `bin_to_nat` is the inverse of `nat_to_bin` though.

Comment: Thank you! I just forgot that **Coq** is a mechanical proof assistant and while it is obvious for us as human beings that `T Z = Z` but **Coq** sees it as a sequence of symbols.

Comment: @Morin `T Z = Z` is false, even for a human. $2 * 0 = 0$ is true, but that's not what `T Z = Z` means. `Z` and `T Z` are not integers, they are representations of integers. Interpreting `T` as doubling and `Z` as zero is an interpretation. Using this interpretation, $2 * 0 = 0$ can be expressed in Coq as `bin_to_nat (T Z) = bin_to_nat Z`.

Comment: Machines are never wrogn.